# How to get parameters in JFormField from a disabled plugin in Joomla 1.6/2.5?

Tags: joomla, parameters

How i can get some parameters from a disabled/not yet actived plugin in joomla 1.6/2.5?

```
$module = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('system','myplugin');
$moduleParams = new JParameter($module->params);
$val = $moduleParams->get("key");
```

This method didn't work becouse i need to use within an element JFormField generator.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can not use this method while your plugin is not activated.

Comment: Just find the answer by myself.

    $data = null;
    foreach ((array) $this->form as $k => $v) {
      if($val instanceof JRegistry){
        $data = &$v;
        break;
      }
    }
    $data = $data->toArray();
    $val = $data['params']['key'];

Thanks! Bye!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the answer by myself.

```
$data = null;
foreach ((array) $this->form as $k => $v) {
  if($val instanceof JRegistry){
    $data = &$v;
    break;
  }
}
$data = $data->toArray();
$val = $data['params']['key'];
```

Thanks! Bye!

Answer (score 2):

With `JPluginHelper::getPlugin` it's possible to access only enabled plugins, so here's the code for direct access to database.

```
// Build query
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
    ->select( 'params' )
    ->from(   '#__extensions' )
    ->where(  'type = ' . $db->q('plugin') )
    ->where(  'folder = ' . $db->q('authentication') )  // Plugin type
    ->where(  'element = ' . $db->q('gmail') )          // Plugin element
;

// Execute query
$db->setQuery($query);

try
{
    $result = $db->loadResult();
}
catch (RuntimeException $e)
{
    return false;
}

// Parse parameters
if (!empty($result))
{
    $params = new JRegistry($result);
    $val    = $params->get('key', 'defaultValue');
}
```

You may store query results in in the JFormField Object so save database queries in case field is availabile multiple times.

```
protected $results = null;
```

Comment: Corrected, indeed you cannot use JPluginHelper for disabled plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may want to try this:

```
// Get plugin parameters
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('`params`')
      ->from  ('`#__extensions`')
      ->where ("`type`    = 'plugin'")
      ->where ("`folder`  = 'system'")
      ->where ("`element` = 'myplugin'");
$db->setQuery($query);
$res = json_decode($db->loadResult(), true);
$val = $res['key'];
```